# Copying the contents of multiple inputs to the clipboard

Tags: jquery, copy

I have some fields with some text. Each field has its own button for copying to the clipboard. But I can't get it to work correctly in any way.

The structure is as follows

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="some text" />
    <span class="copy">Copy!</span>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="some text2" />
    <span class="copy">Copy!</span>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="some text3" />
    <span class="copy">Copy!</span>
</div>
```

The following code works if there is one field, but what if there are several.

```
$('.field').on('click', '.copy', function () {
    var copyText = $('.field input');
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

I probably need something like `each` and `closest`, but I can't figure out how to apply it(

```
$('.field').each(function () {
    var copyText = $('.field input');
    $(this).on('click', '.copy', function () {
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi , just change `$('.field input')` to `$(this).prev()` for first attempt you have made. [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati_911/3r7kaqyf/1/)

Comment: Why didn't you show this as an answer, I would thank you with an assessment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $(this) and prevAll()

https://api.jquery.com/prevall/

```js
$('.field').on('click', '.copy', function () {
    var copyText = $(this).prevAll("input"); 
    var copyTextVal = $(copyText).val();
    $(copyText).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    
    // debug infos 
    console.clear();
    console.log(copyTextVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="some text" />
    <span class="copy">Copy!</span>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="some text2" />
    <span class="copy">Copy!</span>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="some text3" />
    <span class="copy">Copy!</span>
</div>
```